# Offline Data Entry

Tags: html, database, offline

Here's my situation:

My client has an very large database. Currently, they fill out Inspection Forms by hand and manually put them into the database after the inspection. The forms are mostly checkboxes with very few areas for text input. They want to migrate from paper to tablets which are not specific to a single OS. When on the job site, the tablets will usually not be connected to the Internet.

I've been racking my brain for a few days trying to think of a solution. In what way could we record the offline data entry? Is there a way to synchronize the data when reaching an Internet source or would we be better off saving the current information and entering it into the db by hand when the inspectors are back at the office?

I was thinking to use HTML5/JS/PHP as it can easily be used on an android based, iPad, or Windows tablet and be cross compatible. I may be ruling out PHP as neither device should be able to run it locally.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you try so far?

Comment: We're still in the planning phase as we don't want to start without having a seamless plan. I was just looking for the best course of action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you mate.
[Getting Started with HTML5 Local Databases](http://blog.darkcrimson.com/2010/05/local-databases/)

Comment: Don't forget to upvote & accept his answer!

Comment: You can create an app that's HTML5 based and run Local Databases in it. But I suppose that there is a 5MB cache limit. [more on here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531327/using-html5-web-database-to-store-files-for-offline-access)

Comment: I have to wait 6 minutes, Charlie. I've been trying.